# use setTimeout in a for loop

Tags: javascript, settimeout

i need to get this code in a for loop.so i don't have to write it 4 times,i just can't make it work.

```
setTimeout(
    function(){
        document.getElementById("square").style.left="0px";
    },0);

setTimeout(
    function(){
        document.getElementById("square").style.left="100px";
    },1000);

setTimeout(
    function(){
        document.getElementById("square").style.left="200px";
    },2000);

setTimeout(
    function(){
        document.getElementById("square").style.left="300px";
    },3000);
```

my answer so far is this

```
for (i = 0; i <=300; i=i+100) {
    j = i*10;
    setTimeout(
        function (){
            document.getElementById("square").style.left=i+"px";
        }, j);
};
```

Comment: apart from maybe initializing j and i using `var`, whats wrong? Also your for loop has a colon at the end it doesn't need.

Comment: @user1102901: `i` is not what you think it is.

Answer (score 5):

Here you go:

```
var square = document.getElementById('square');

for (var i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        square.style.left = i * 100 + 'px';
    }, i * 1000);
}
```

**UPDATE** (now using a closure)

http://jsfiddle.net/c03hf5t5/

```
var square = document.getElementById('square');

for (var i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
    setTimeout(setLeft(square, i * 100), i * 1000);
}

function setLeft(element, offset) {
  return function() {
    element.style.left = offset + 'px';
  };
}
```

Comment: check out my answer, ive dealt with this before.

Comment: I updated mine as well to address the issue.

Answer (score 3):

This should work for you. I think the loop will not wait for `setTimeout`, that was your problem.

```
var square = document.getElementById('square');

function changeLeftPos(i, elem) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        elem.style.left = i * 100 + 'px';
    }, i * 1000);
}

for (var i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
    changeLeftPos(i, square);
}
```

Comment: yep! this one works! thanks a lot =

Answer (score 2):

The reason dhouty's solution doesnt work is because loops have issues carrying incremented values inside asynchronous functions.

```
var square = document.getElementById('square');
for (var i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
    (function(i){
        setTimeout(function() {
            square.style.left = i * 100 + 'px';
        }, i * 1000);
    })(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var square = document.getElementById('square');
var i=0;
function example()
{
    square.style.left = i * 100 + 'px';
    if (i < 3){
        i++;
        setTimeout(example, 1000);
    }
}
setTimeout(example, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var v = [0, 100, 200, 300], c;
    for (ct = 0; ct <= v.length - 1; ct++) {
        setTimeout(
            function () {
                var vl = ct;
                (function () {
                    document.getElementById("square").style.left = vl + "px"
                }())
            }
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because the anonymous function supplied to `setTimeout` will be run after the for loop, regardless of the time specified.

At this point the variable of `i` that the function looks at is the current variable of `i` at the **end** of the loop, as the setTimeout function executes after the loop.

A `for` loop doesn't create a closure as there is no blocked scope in javascript.  To fix your problem you will need this (or something to similar effect):

```
for (i = 0; i <=300; i=i+100) {
       j = i*10;
    (function(val) {
    setTimeout(
      function (val){
         document.getElementById("square").style.left=val+"px";
    }, j))(i);

};
```

The function here introduces a closure which means that the value of `i` will refer to the current value of `i` rather than what it will be after the loop has run.